# Is it normal for a new Shimano hub to feel rough?

Tags: shimano, hub

I have recently purchased a brand new Shimano HB-M7110-B front hub. When I unpacked it and started rotating it with my fingers (as you always must) I noticed that it actually felt quite rough, almost like a light pepper grinder. Is this normal for a new hub, or is it an indication that it is defective?

Answer (score 11):

The intention is for it to be adjusted after the wheel is built but before it's ridden.

Tension on the flanges has some effect on preload. Were it a QR hub, there's also the fact that some play is desirable off the bike, but not when the wheel is being built. This applies less or not at all to Shimano thru-axle hubs, because the adjustment doesn't usually change when installed onto the bike, unlike a QR.

Answer (score 6):

In the past I have found many new wheelsets feel like they are tight. I have loosened them to what I thought was reasonable and installed them. Within 25 miles they felt loose. The lesson learned is that many times new bearings feel tighter than you would like but quickly loosen up.